# Replacing an element (div) with another (div)

Tags: javascript, html, function

I've been trying to create a function that allow to move around a website without leaving the same page, just loading different contents on click.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Freud Got Lynched</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="site.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Manrope:wght@200;300;400;500;523;600;700;800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="site.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="abertura" class="page0">
    <video autoplay muted loop>
        <source src="assets/fundo1.webm" type="video/webm">
      </video>
      <div class="info">
          <img src="assets/logo.png" alt="logo" class="logobig">
          <p class="texto">Um documentário interativo inspirado nas obras do realizador David Lynch... 
            ou uma viagem pelo subconsciente incomum de pessoas comuns enquanto dormem.</p>
          <p class="sonhar">Sonhar</p>
          <a href="javascript:showPage('page1')"><img src="assets/botao2.png" alt="botao" class="botao"></a>
          </div>
  </div>
        <div id="segunda" class="page1">
          <img src="assets/fundo.png" class="fundo">
                <div class="container">
                        <div id="myNav" class="overlay">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav();">&times;</a>
                            <div class="overlay-content">
                              <ul><li><a href="#">Episódios</a></li>
                                <ul><li><a href="#">Episódio 1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Episódio 2</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Episódio 3</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Episódio 4</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Episódio 5</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Episódio 6</a></li>
                                </ul>
                                <li><a href="sobre.html">Sobre</a></li>
                                <li><a href="sobre.html#autores">Autores</a></li>
                                <li><a href="sobre.html#creditos">Créditos</a></li>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="botaomenu" onclick="myFunction(this); openNav();">
                            <div class="bar1"></div>
                            <div class="bar2"></div>
                            <div class="bar3"></div>
                </div>
                <img src="assets/logo.png" alt="logo" class="logomedium" onclick="showPage('page0')"></div>
        </div>
```

I have this function on Javascript

```
function showPage(id) {

  if (id=="page1") {
    var pages = document.querySelectorAll("div");
    for (var i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
      pages[i].style.display = "none";
    }

    var le = document.getElementById('segunda');
    le.style.display = "block";
  }
```

The problem is that not all of the contents in the div#segunda are being loaded after the click triggers the function. All the elements of the div#abertura are removed, as it's supposed to do, but the only element that shows from the div#segunda is the img.fundo.

Any ideas? Please keep in mind that i'm a beginner in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you have `div`s inside `segunda` div. A better way to approach this would be to assign a class to the top-level divs, and then hide them using that class. For example here's an abridged version of the code.

```html
<body>
<div id="1" class="container">...</div>
<div id="2" class="container">...</div>
</body>
```

Along with JS like

```
function showPage(id) {

  if (id=="page1") {
    var pages = document.document.getElementsByClassName("container");
    for (var i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
      pages[i].style.display = "none";
    }

    var le = document.getElementById('segunda');
    le.style.display = "block";
  }
```

Comment: Not sure I follow. Should the div with the class "container" be surrounding div.abertura and div.segunda?

Comment: `div.abertura` and `div.segunda` should have the `container` class, as they are the only ones we want to hide. If you hide all divs you will have to unhide the divs under `div.segunda` as well.

Comment: Ok, so I added the `conteudo` class to `div.abertura` and `div.segunda`, and also changed the pages variable to `var pages = document.getElementsByClassName("conteudo")`, but the final result didn't change.

Answer (score 0):

Your html is missing some closing tags, so it is invalid. I have also fixed that.
Now, the changes:

- It is a good idea to give your "pages" a common way to identify them so that you can query the DOM only for them. In this case, I have given them the class `page`. Your problem was that by doing `var pages = document.querySelectorAll("div");` you were basically selecting all the `div`s on the page and then hide them, which has an undesired effect.
- Next, it is also a good idea to uniquely identify the page containers somehow. This can be achieved by giving them an `id`. It is a good idea to have a format for these ids so you can easily work with them. In this case, I have given them the id `page_x`, where `x` is a number.
- Going to the `showPage` function, we are now able to pass just the number of the page we want, e.g. `showPage(1)`. Because we have a certain format for the ids, it is now more elegant to work with them. As you can see in the function, I used the `.page` class and then I compared the ids in the loop to determine what is to be shown and what to hide.
- Another option would be to have `display: none;` on the `.page` class in css and have another class called `active` with `display: block;` and then just add this class to the `div` you wish to show and remove it from the others

Here's the updated html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Freud Got Lynched</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="site.css">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Manrope:wght@200;300;400;500;523;600;700;800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="site.js"></script>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="page_0" class="page">
         <video autoplay muted loop>
            <source src="assets/fundo1.webm" type="video/webm">
         </video>
         <div class="info">
            <img src="assets/logo.png" alt="logo" class="logobig">
            <p class="texto">Um documentário interativo inspirado nas obras do realizador David Lynch... 
               ou uma viagem pelo subconsciente incomum de pessoas comuns enquanto dormem.
            </p>
            <p class="sonhar">Sonhar</p>
            <a href="javascript:showPage(1)"><img src="assets/botao2.png" alt="botao" class="botao"></a>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div id="page_1" class="page" style='display: none;'>
         <img src="assets/fundo.png" class="fundo">
         <div class="container">
            <div id="myNav" class="overlay">
               <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav();">&times;</a>
               <div class="overlay-content">
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Episódios</a></li>
                      <ul>
                         <li><a href="#">Episódio 1</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Episódio 2</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Episódio 3</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Episódio 4</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Episódio 5</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Episódio 6</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    <li><a href="sobre.html">Sobre</a></li>
                    <li><a href="sobre.html#autores">Autores</a></li>
                    <li><a href="sobre.html#creditos">Créditos</a></li>
                  </ul>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="botaomenu" onclick="myFunction(this); openNav();">
               <div class="bar1"></div>
               <div class="bar2"></div>
               <div class="bar3"></div>
            </div>
            <img src="assets/logo.png" alt="logo" class="logomedium" onclick="showPage(0)">
         </div>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And js function:

```
function showPage(id) {
    let pages = document.querySelectorAll(".page");

    for (var i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
        if(pages[i].id !== `page_${id}`) {
        pages[i].style.display = "none";
      } else {
        pages[i].style.display = "block";
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: I created a new document to test this code out, It didn't work. `div#page_1` is never hidden and nothing happens with onclick event.

Comment: It doesn't work with my code as css gets involved, but even in your example the list element shows up when you first load the code and it shouldn't since it's included in `div#page_1`.

Comment: You may have other problems too. There you go https://jsfiddle.net/zxym8r79/ . Also updated my answer.

Comment: I'm getting this error: 
VM91:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: showPage is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1